# Default ViewController naming regarding given project name

Tags: ios, xcode4.6

I'm quite a newbie in developing iOS app as using the most recent version of xCode, V4.6 as IDE. 
I'm building a application for testing. Let's say I give this iOS application a name "newApp".
 when creating a project, it should by default generate newAppViewController.h and newAppViewController.m for me, as in examples from almost every iOS books.

But in my case, it's only giving me viewController files with, shortened names, as only viewController.h and viewController.m as their names. Anything could be wrong with my current XCode setup?

It would actually not be that big deal to me, but rather could be a big time saving for my iOS study as to reference to what is generally used in the books.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should be naming your apps starting with a capital: "NewApp" instead of "newApp". It won't change anything, but that's the common convention.

If you want to have "NewAppViewController" and "NewAppAppDelegate", add "NewApp" to the "Class Prefix" box in the second screen. If you've already progressed on your app, use the "Refactor" command to rename your classes. Here's the result of putting "NewApp" into the "Class Prefix" box:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 6 the name of your project is not being attached to the beginning of the classes names. It is optional. You can check the prefix square when creating the new project for that. Just checkmate the class prefix to add the name of the project to the begging of your app or otherwise xcode creates the classes with no project name and just what the classes are.

Answer (score 0):

I generally enter a class prefix on the "Choose options for your new project" page. If your new app is named "newApp", I'd use a prefix of NA. Then all classes will have the NA prefix so that you won't have naming collisions.